# Postgres "Command Not Found"

Tags: postgresql, shell, unix, redhat

I have looked at the majority of "Command Not Found" errors with Postgres and none of them are similiar to what I am running into. On my server Postgres is running effectively, as I can log into an individual database with no issues; however, when logging into the server as user postgres to run commands such as \list or create new databases I get the following error:

```
-bash-4.1$ \list
-bash: list: command not found
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening. When I was trying to troubleshoot this I thought I might be in the wrong directory so I ran `pwd` and this is what I get:

```
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try the command `psql -l`. If that works, try `psql postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\list` is no bash command, but from the command/output you posted it looks you are tryin to call it directly from within bash.

First run the `psql` command, when you have you should have an interactive session with it. There you should be able to use the `\list` command. You can read more about this [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-psql.html).